# Trigger parent id sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

The following

```
SELECT @parent =  object_name(parent_id) from sys.triggers where name = 'tr1'
```

Will return the table name, but I was wondering if it's possible to return it's object id?

I thought object_id may do that but returns null.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT @parent =  object_id(object_name(parent_id)) from sys.triggers where name = 'tr1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188746.aspx) of the sys.triggers table. You might be getting problems due to this? But, I might also just be misunderstanding the question.

```
For DML triggers, this is the object_id of the table 
    or view on which the DML trigger is defined.
```